# TestComplete_JavaScripting_how to hide web url path while performing any operation for any object in script

Tags: testcomplete

I'm new to use Testcomplete , i'm using javascripts to automate my code, below are sample script ( converted one recorded first then converted into jscript) and in this scripts what i observe that TestComplete identified and captured the object element by using complete web url path not on only object specific .

```
efunction Test_Login   {var UserName, Password, TestEnv;UserName = "XYZ";Pwd = "XYZXYZ";TestEnv   = "https://test.Env.com/";Browsers.Item(btChrome).Run("TestEnv",1);Aliases.browser.pageTestenvCom.formFrmlogincomponent.textboxUsername.SetText("UserName");Aliases.browser.pageTestenvCom.formFrmlogincomponent.passwordboxPassword.SetText("Pwd");Aliases.browser.pageTestenvCom.formFrmlogincomponent.buttonLogin.ClickButton();}e
```

what i means lets see below example of login page

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we record any Test case in Test-Complete, it stores all the object in the Naming Repository and then access the same.

This helps test-complete in easily recognisation of object and can improve the speed of test-case, in case there are multiple objects visible on screen

You can go through following link for more info on Name Mapping.

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/object-identification/name-mapping/overview.html